# Generate a word search puzzle matrix

Tags: python, string, matrix, coordinates, words

I'm not sure of the rules to create a matrix for a word search puzzle game. I am able to create a matrix with initial values of 0.

Is it correct that **I'll randomly select a starting point(coordinates), and a random direction(horizontally,vertically,&,diagonally) for a word then manage if it would overlap with another word in the matrix?** If it does then check if the characters are the same (although there's only a little chance) then if no I'll assign it there. The problem is it's like I lessen the chance of words to overlap.

I have also read that I need to check first the words that have the same characters. But if that's the case, it seems like the words that I am going to put in the matrix are always overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather look at words that are already there and then randomly select a word from the set of words that fit there.
Of course you might not fill the whole matrix like this. If you have put  one word somewhere where it blocks all other words (no other word fits), you might have to backtrack, but that will kill the running time.

If you really want to fill the whole matrix, I would iterate over all possible starting positions, see how many words fit there, and then recurse over the possibilities of the starting position with the least number of candidates. That will cause your program recognize and leave "dead ends" early, which improves the running time drastically. That is a powerful technique from fixed parameter algorithms, which I like to call Branching-vector minimization.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the longest word.
First of all you must find all points and directions, where this word may fit. For example word 'WORD' may fit, when at the first pos there is NULL or W, on the second pos NULL or O, on the third NULL or R and on the fourth NULL or D.

Then You should group it to positions with no NULLS, with one NULL, with two NULLs and so on.

Then select randomly position from the group with the smallest ammount of NULLS. If there are no posible positions, skip the word.

This attempt will allow you to put more words and prevent situations, where random search can't find the proper place (when there is only a few of them).